# Basic for loop is not working

Tags: python, for-loop

I am new to Python and I am trying to write a `for` loop to go through a list of results, doing some calculations on them and then print them, but it is not working.

As I have said, I am new to this and trying to learn, if anybody has had experience with this could you please explain to me, I know it is probably a silly mistake but I cannot see it.

```
for test in test_set:
    person_id = test['person_id']
    place_id = test['place_id']
    rating = test['rating']
    predicted_rating = simple_nearestneighbours(person_id, place_id, 50)



    n = 0
    while n < 50:

     mae = (abs(predicted_rating - rating))

    #return mae/ 5
   # print mae/50
 print "MAE " + str(mae/50)
```

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? As it stands, you never increment `n`, so the `while` loop will run forever.

Comment: I originally didnt have n=0 and the while loop, I thought the code would run through the list of ratings because of the for test in test _set, and do the calculations but it didnt so that's when I add it. The output is one number, i'm expecting a lot more than that.

Comment: It only happens once because you `print` *outside* the loop. Indent it one tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` loop runs infinitely as `n` will always be less than `50` (you never change its value from `0`), thus meaning your `for` loop gets stuck.

---

You could fix the `while` loop by incrementing `n` with `n += 1` within the loop, but using a `while` loop is pointless here.

Instead of your `while` loop, I would just use a `for` loop instead:

```
for n in range(50):
```

This is better because you are essentially just iterating upwards an equal amount each time- the condition will always be fulfilled at the same moment.

Comment: thank you! unfortunately it is not printing what I thought it would print but at least now I know why it wasn't working

Answer (score 1):

You are not incrementing the value of `n` in `while` loop.

This causes the `while` loop to run indefinitely, which in turn causes the `for` loop to run indefinitely.

Add a statement `n += 1` in the `while` loop, if you really want to use it there.